# How can I force a gradle build to re-download a SNAPSHOT plugin from Maven repository on every build

Tags: gradle, dependencies, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

As shown below, I have a gradle plugin that is built deployed as a SNAPSHOT version in a maven repository.

I am aware that `-SNAPSHOT` dependencies should automatically be recognised as `changing=true`

I also know that the `resolutionStrategy` should allow forcing a new download for all configurations.

However, in this context, the setting has no effect.

**Question**: Can you provide a corrected sample, based on the one below, that forces a re-download on every run, or explain how such a configuration can be achieved?

```
buildscript {
    repositories { maven { url "http://moomoomoo.com:8081/artifactory/moomoomoo-plugins" } }
    dependencies { classpath 'com.moomoomoo:moomootools:1.3-SNAPSHOT' }
}

configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds' }

apply plugin: 'com.moomoomoo.moomootool'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure the resolution strategy of the classpath configuration for the build script you have to configure it inside the `buildscript` block:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { maven { url "http://moomoomoo.com:8081/artifactory/moomoomoo-plugins" } }
    configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds' }
    dependencies { classpath 'com.moomoomoo:moomootools:1.3-SNAPSHOT' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.moomoomoo.moomootool'
```